# htaccess redirection working for on file but not working for other files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Below is my htaccess file.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/view_campaign\.php\?var1=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ view_campaign/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^view_campaign/([0-9]+)$ /view_campaign.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ view_campaign.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/profile_view\.php\?id1=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ profile_view/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^profile_view/([0-9]+)$ /profile_view.php?id1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ profile_view.php?id1=$2&name2=$3 [NC,L]
```

and here are my urls/

```
http://localhost/profile_view/1/test
http://localhost/view_campaing/1/test-campaign-name
```

with some php code my link for view_campaign is redirecting properly. i can say my links for view_campaign is working fine. if it appears like below.

```
http://localhost/view_campaign/1/test-campaign-name-some-junk
http://localhost/view_campaign/1
http://localhost/view_campaign/1/
```

I want the same for profile_view. i copy pasted the same code in htaccess/php file and change relevant things. 
Issue is if i try to open `http://localhost/profile_view/1/test` or `http://localhost/profile_view/1` or `http://localhost/profile_view/1/`
it is redirecting to

```
http://localhost/view_campaign/1/test-campaign-name-some-junk
```

I don't have much understanding about htaccess.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make some changes in anubhava answer. Now, it is working fine.
Below is the working code.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/view_campaign\.php\?var1=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ view_campaign/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/profile_view\.php\?var1=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ profile_view/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^view_campaign/([0-9]+)$ /view_campaign.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(view_campaign)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ view_campaign.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^profile_view/([0-9]+)$ /profile_view.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(profile_view)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ profile_view.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have it this way:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/view_campaign\.php\?var1=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ view_campaign/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/profile_view\.php\?id1=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ profile_view/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(view_campaign|profile_view)/(\d+)$ $1.php?var1=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(view_campaign|profile_view)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you explain me what am i missing?

Comment: @404 your last rule in view_campaign matches every url so it never goes over to view_profile page

Comment: I used your code but it is not working as view_campaign and profile_view both are returning error 404.